# Docker for AWS Lambda fails to connect the handler

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I have created a Docker container to be used as a Lambda function using the amazon/aws-lambda-provided image as the base. In spite of copying and providing the handler function, the handler is null.

The Docker file is

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-provided
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY ./index.js ./
#COPY ./lamb.sh ./

ENTRYPOINT [ "/lambda-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

This is run as

```
docker run -it --rm -p 9000:8080 authorizeasset:latest index.handler
```

This results in
`exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)`

Although the handler is passed, it does not get connected. We can see this above "handler="

The file index.js is present in /var/task

```
module.exports.handler = function  myfunc(event) {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };

    console.info("myfunc()")
    return response;
};
```

I have tried to debug this for over 12 hours by

Overriding the entry point to `/bin/sh` and running the code on the CLI of the docker image. Trying to set the `_HANDLER` environment variable on the shell, running the `/lamda-entrypoint.sh` on the command line and passing `index.handler` as a parameter etc. but no luck. Every single attempt gives the same result.

Based on some responses from AWS, I used AWS SAM CLI to build the image and run the container. This built the following DOCKER file

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14

COPY app.js package.json ./

RUN npm install

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.lambdaHandler"]
```

using `sam build` and `sam local invoke` works and we get the result. This does not explain the cause however.

I took the same Docker file and used `docker build` and built the image and ran it with `docker run` but once this is done, again I see the same problem. So what is SAM CLI doing? I want to understand this at the fundamental level and not let SAM do some magic.

Comment: First off it looks like you're building with amazon's base lambda image which would not have a nodejs environment installed. You should try using amazon's dedicated nodejs image for lambda or use your own node env and install the lambda runtime. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-1